# Prevent a div to overlap over a fixed one

Tags: css, html

I want to create a webpage that has a fixed part at the bottom and, at the top, a part that will be filled dynamically with content, this dynamic part should have a scroll bar should the added content not fit, in order to stay above the fixed part.

**style.css:**

```
.action-box{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <!-- this will be filled with content -->
  </div>
  <div class="action-box">
    <!-- this is the fixed part -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paullik/RdGXt/) that the two `div`s overlap.

How can I make the first `div` scrollable, so that it won't slide over or below the last `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll propose using dynamic resizing, depending on window height:

Here is `jQuery` example:

```
function adjustBlocks() {
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var boxH = $('#action-box').height();
    $('#content').height((winH - boxH) + 'px');
}

$(document).ready(adjustBlocks);

$(window).resize(adjustBlocks);
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="action-box"></div>
```

And sample CSS:

```
#content{
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#action-box{
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffccaa;
}
```

Of course, you can easily add any margins and mention them in `jQuery` resizing function.

Oh, and the [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RdGXt/150/)

Comment: Using this solution I got rid of the fixed div :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to apply `margin-bottom` to the div on top that matches the total height of the fixed div at the  bottom, and you have to give the div at the bottom a height along with a background color so the other div doesn't show through.

```
.action-box{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;   
}

.content {margin-bottom: 50px}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RdGXt/151/

Comment: Doesn't work, they will still overlap since the bottom is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a css class with a fixed height and `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: Isn't there a way without fixed height? Maybe on some displays it won't show up correctly.

Comment: You're already using fixed position... Shouldn't be any different.

Comment: With a fixed height, it won't be able to scale with browsers height.